# Querying partitions/drives on a remote server with WMI

Tags: powershell, wmi

I do the following to check for local drives/partitions on a remote computer:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -ComputerName SERVERNAME -Filter "Description='Default share'"
```

but the command also returns CD-roms etc.
Is there a command to only return disk/partitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3" | 
Foreach-Object {$_.DeviceID}
```

Comment: It would help if `DriveType` was explained... The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) say DriveType `3` means a `Local Disk` (`5` is a Compact Disc).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I ended up doing (I actually found it out just before you posted the solution:))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_DiskPartition  -computername remotecomp |

ForEach-Object {
$info = @{}
$info.Disk = $_.DiskIndex
$info.Partition = $_.Index 
$info.DriveLetter = $_.psbase.GetRelated('Win32_LogicalDisk') |     
Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeviceID    
    New-Object PSObject -Property $info
}

$info # contains partions number and unit letter as hashtable
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-WmiObject -query "Select * from Win32_DiskPartition"` ... maybe?